# Input data must be multiple of cipher block size in AES CTR mode

Tags: flutter, encryption, dart, aes

I get this exception when I use Dart's [encrypt package](https://pub.dev/packages/encrypt) to decrypt something using AES CTR mode:

```
E/flutter (19095): Invalid argument(s): Input data length must be a multiple of cipher's block size
E/flutter (19095): #0      PaddedBlockCipherImpl.process (package:pointycastle/padded_block_cipher/padded_block_cipher_impl.dart:55:9)
E/flutter (19095): #1      AES.decrypt (package:encrypt/src/algorithms/aes.dart:38:20)
```

Here is my code:

```
final encrypter = encrypt.Encrypter(encrypt.AES(key, mode: encrypt.AESMode.ctr));
final decrypted = encrypter.decrypt(encrypt.Encrypted.fromBase16(cipher), iv: iv);
```

`cipher` is hexadecimal string of length 10.  I thought AES CTR mode did not require any padding.  If it does require padding, what do I pad with?  I tried this:

```
final decrypted = encrypter.decrypt(encrypt.Encrypted.fromBase16(cipher.padRight(16, null)), iv: iv);
```

But I get the following exception:

```
E/flutter (19095): FormatException: Invalid radix-16 number (at character 1)
E/flutter (19095): nu
E/flutter (19095): ^
```

Using `'0'` as the padding results in the first exception I describe.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this package, but I would assume this is a bug - your thinking is correct,  CTR doesn't require padding.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a problem in Dart's encrypt package.  It cannot handle something encrypted using AES CTR mode if it isn't a multiple of the block size.  This package is wrapper for [Pointy Castle](https://pub.dev/packages/pointycastle), which I was able to use successfully to decrypt a string encrypted using AES CTR mode.  Here's the code:

```
import 'package:encrypt/encrypt.dart' as encrypt;
import 'package:pointycastle/export.dart' as pc;

String decrypt(String cipher, Uint8List key, Uint8List iv) {
  final encryptedText = encrypt.Encrypted.fromBase16(cipher);
  final ctr = pc.CTRStreamCipher(pc.AESFastEngine())
    ..init(false, pc.ParametersWithIV(pc.KeyParameter(key.bytes), iv.bytes));
  Uint8List decrypted = ctr.process(encryptedText.bytes);

  print(String.fromCharCodes(decrypted));

  return String.fromCharCodes(decrypted);
}
```

`cipher` is a hexadecimal string.  encrypt's package is still useful because it provides utilities for converting a hexadecimal string to a Uint8List

Answer (score 0):

I Got this when i was trying to decrypt a file that was not encrypted. Just change the input to be a file that is already encrypted.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).